# Google font locally with different weights but with the same name

Tags: css, font-face, font-family, google-fonts

Here's my problem:

In order to improve my SPEED mark on google speed insight, I had to switch from render-blocking google fonts to loaded locally google fonts.

So far so good except that I have a HUGE problem.

Before I was loading my fonts in this way:

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,600,700|Open+Sans+Condensed:300|Ubuntu+Condensed|Ubuntu:300,700" rel="stylesheet">
```

And in my huge style-sheet, I was just calling them normally for example:

```
body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
}
```

But now, since I had to download them to avoid the render-blocking red flag, I'm calling them in this way:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "Opens Sans";
    src: url("/fonts/OpenSans-Regular.ttf");
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
}
@font-face {
    font-family: "Opens Sans";
    src: url("/fonts/OpenSans-Light.ttf");
    font-weight: 300;
}
@font-face {
    font-family: "Opens Sans";
    src: url("/fonts/OpenSans-Bold.ttf");
    font-weight: 600;
}
@font-face {
    font-family: "Opens Sans";
    src: url("/fonts/OpenSans-ExtraBold.ttf");
    font-weight: 700;
}
@font-face {
    font-family: "Opens Sans Condensed";
    src: url("/fonts/OpenSansCondensed-Light.ttf");
    font-weight: 300;
}
@font-face {
    font-family: "Ubuntu Condensed";
    src: url("/fonts/UbuntuCondensed-Regular.ttf");
    font-weight: 300;
}
@font-face {
    font-family: "Ubuntu";
    src: url("/fonts/Ubuntu-Regular.ttf");
    font-weight: 300;
}
@font-face {
    font-family: "Ubuntu";
    src: url("/fonts/Ubuntu-Bold.ttf");
    font-weight: 700;
}
```

And here you can see my PROBLEM.

I call different fonts with the same name, but they have different weights. Obviously, I can call them with a different name, for example, "Ubuntu Bold" but then I would have to change my entire stylesheet, for example, I should now declare:

```
body {
      font-family: 'Open Sans Normal', sans-serif;
      // font-weight: 400; //
}
p {
      font-family: 'Open Sans Bold', sans-serif;
      // font-weight: 700; //
}
```

Essentially, no more font-weight, only different font-family names to state the weight.

Is there any solution to my problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Even though the font files are different, you don't need to set a different `font-family` for each variation of the font. You can just set one `font-family`, and specify the different variations in the different `@font-face` properties.

You should define each `@font-face` with the same `font-family` name, like so:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Opens Sans';
    src: url("/fonts/OpenSans-Regular.ttf");
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Opens Sans';
    src: url("/fonts/OpenSans-Italic.ttf");
    font-style: italic;
    font-weight: 400;
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Opens Sans';
    src: url("/fonts/OpenSans-Bold.ttf");
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 600;
}
```

Note that each different font file has a separate `@font-face` with different properties that correspond to the specific font file, but they have the same `font-family`. You can then use the font in your css like so:

```
body {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
}
.bold {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 600;
}
.italic {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-style: italic;
}
```

The other properties in your css classes (`font-weight`, `font-style`, etc) will determine which `@font-face` is used.